# Boolean Currying Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, currying

I am trying to write a boolean currying function in javascript.

```js
let s = "ajkjxa";

function isPresent(a) {

return function (b) {

  if (b) {
    return isPresent(s.includes(b) && s.includes(a));
  } else {
    return s.includes(a);
  }
 };
}

console.log(isPresent("a")("j")("x")());//true expected
console.log(isPresent("a")("j")("x")('b')());//false expected
```

I want isPresent function should return true if the passed arguments present is the given string else it should return false.

Comment: `isPresenst(a)` expects `a` to be a string, but in the recursive call you are passing it a boolean. That's just not going to work.

Comment: then how can I recursively pass the previous result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic solution is to have the "accumulator" value passed in differently. The first call you do to `isPresent` should already call the closure, and `isPresent()` should also work.

```js
function makePresenceChecker(string, found) {
  return function(char) {
    if (char == undefined)
      return found;
    else
      return makePresenceChecker(string, found && string.includes(char));
  };
}

const isPresent = makePresenceChecker("ajkjxa", true);

console.log(isPresent("a")("j")("x")()); // true
console.log(isPresent("a")("j")("x")('b')()); // false
```

You can also write that with an IIFE:

```js
const string = "ajkjxa";
const isPresent = (function makePresenceChecker(found) {
  return function(char) {
    if (char == undefined)
      return found;
    else
      return makePresenceChecker(found && string.includes(char));
  };
})(true);

console.log(isPresent("a")("j")("x")()); // true
console.log(isPresent("a")("j")("x")('b')()); // false
```

Comment: can we update this use case: console.log(newValid("b",'kl')("kj")("j")());//false expected

Comment: @Infopedia I don't know what `newValid("b", 'kl')` is supposed to mean. I would suggest to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about your new use case.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.I meant, can we update this use case: console.log(isPresent("b",'kl')("kj")("j")());//false expected.

Comment: @Infopedia Ok, but still what do you want to achieve by passing two arguments into the first call?

Answer (score -1):

I'm mostly answering this as a learning exercise. After much struggling I have something I know works. I've used different syntax and naming than your initial example, and I pass the initial string in a setup call.

It's possible this isn't strictly "currying" since we only need to aggregate the booleans. It didn't seem necessary to compile a list of function calls since the boolean results are sufficient.

As mentioned in comments, returning a function at the end is unnecessary at least in pure JS. In TypeScript that I wrote this in, I can't get the type to work this way. (The return type depends on the argument type, and you can't call a `(boolean | function)` if that is what is returned.)

```js
const startcurry = start => { // string   
   const results = []; // boolean[] (could be boolean instead)

   function inner(maybeNext) { // string?
      if (maybeNext) {
         const next = maybeNext; // string (just for naming rule)
         results.push(start.includes(next));
         return inner;
      }
        
      return results.every(x => x);
   }

   return inner;
};

const s = "ajkjxa";
console.log(startcurry(s)("a")("j")("x")());           // true expected
console.log(startcurry(s)("a")("j")("x")('b')());      // false expected
console.log(startcurry(s)("a")("j")("x")('k')());      // true expected
console.log(startcurry(s)("a")("j")("x")('k')('c')()); // false expected
console.log(startcurry(s)());                          // true expected
console.log(startcurry(s)("b")("a")());                // false expected
```

Comment: You can remove the need for the double `()()` by changing `return () => results.every(x => x);` to `return results.every(x => x);` directly.

Comment: @Halcyon thanks, I think I see that too, but it's tricky what the types would be. I actually wrote this in TypeScript, and it doesn't like the resulting type of `inner` if it doesn't return a function. it's tricky since it's a recursive type definition (the type is a function that returns either a boolean or <self>).

Comment: What type did you end up with for the `inner` function? I can't find anything that works on the call-side. Is there a way to get ts to recognize the return-type changes if you pass 0 or 1 argument? Something like `type innerFn = ((maybeNext: string) => innerFn) | (() => boolean)` doesn't work.

Comment: @Halcyon that's what I mean, that's what I got too. it's like it still considers calling that to result in `(boolean | innerFn)` which is not callable. (also it's not easy to define the function that way without using `any` or something.)

Comment: @Halcyon You'll probably need to overload it instead: `type InnerFn = { (): boolean; (next: string): InnerFn; }`

Comment: @Bergi yup that works. didn't know the right syntax to overload it in a type definition. thanks Bergi.

Answer (score -1):

You can just change it so it checks for 'a' everytime but calls isPresent(b) recursively, if it exists

```js
let s = "ajkjxa";

function isPresent(a, valid=true) {
  return function (b) {
    let isValid = valid && s.includes(a);
    if (b) return isPresent(b, isValid)
    return isValid
    };
}

console.log(isPresent("a")("j")("x")());//true expected
console.log(isPresent("a")("j")("x")('b')());//false expected
console.log(isPresent("a")("g")("l")());//false expected 
console.log(isPresent("a")("s")("b")("b")());//false expected
console.log(isPresent("a")("s")("l")("a")());//false expected
```

EDIT: Moved to a default parameters, less code and it works for the use cases in the comment.

Comment: getting error for these use cases:                                                
console.log(isPresent("a")("g")("l")());//false expected
console.log(isPresent("a")("s")("b")("b")());//false expected

Comment: I didn't take them into account, you are correct, I changed my answer to a cleaner, less code approach that includes those cases.